# Database design. Double relationship

Tags: database, database-design

I am developing a database that shows the educational process in college. 
Students specialize in the departments and they have a supervisor of their department.
In the fourth year students write bachelor's graduate work, which criticizes a teacher from another department.
I identified several entities: departments, students, teachers. And additional entity: works

**STUDENTS** table

- stud_id
- name
- dep_id

**WORKS** table

- work_id
- title
- supervisor_id
- critic_id
- stud_id

**TEACHERS** table

- teach_id
- name
- dep_id

**DEPARTMENS** table

- dep_id
- title

It turns out that the fields supervisor_id and critic_id link to a field  teach_id in the table TEACHERS. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think that is a problem? To me it makes sense if a teacher is either supervisor or reviewer (my understanding of critic_id) or a given piece of work.

Comment: I do not think you need extra table. What you have are 1:1 relationships and they are absolutely fine. Just make sure you properly reference mandatory and optional sides (i.e. the case where teacher may not be a supervisor) and enforce referential integrity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the case where a Teacher may not also be a Supervisor.

You need an extra table- SUPERVISORS, just like TEACHERS, however, instead of "name" and "dep_id", those fields go into another table called "STAFF".

So, SUPERVISORS and TEACHERS both have a field called "staff_id" which joins to STAFF for their name/department, and SUPERVISOR_ID links to a SUPERVISOR, while CRITIC_ID links to a TEACHER.

To summarize, 6 tables: STUDENTS, STAFF, WORKS, TEACHERS, SUPERVISORS, DEPARTMENTS.

Join Works to Students by stud_id, to Supervisors by supervisor_id, and to Teachers by critic_id

Join Supervisors to Staff by staff_id

Join Teachers to Staff by staff_id

Join Staff to Departments by dep_id

Make sense?

Comment: I think the supervisor table would be redundant. Better to have 1:1 relationships and make sure optional side is referenced

Comment: I'm avoiding having 2 fields both link to the same table so that you can have the set of Teachers be different to the set of Supervisors (assuming you can only criticize a teacher). Each of those tables just links to a Staff Member.

Answer (score 0):

As going through your scenario, the primary key and foreign key should be referenced well....
As `critic_id` and `supervisor_id` are linked to `teach_id`, they should be foreign key of `teach_id`.....In this way, you would have normalized db too....